# extract order id from a string using preg match in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have parsed an email body into a string in php.  In this email there is a lot of information.  I need to extract the order id by the best possible method.  The line is:

Order ID:  123456789

It will always be numbers.  The length varies.

Thank you greatly for any help

Comment: I do not know regex at all, i wrote a function to find the character placement of Order ID, then read each character after until it is not a number.  It is silly.

Comment: give an example. Did you want to extract this "Order ID: 123456789" from a bunch of lines?

Comment: i do not want to use it, i know this can be done with a regex, one line.  Yes, but just return the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following.

```
preg_match('/Order\s*ID:\s*([0-9]+)/i', $string, $id);
echo $id[1];
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/164608)

Comment: PERFECT!  I was testing. I really need to learn regex, i'm a dinosaur sometimes

Answer (score 0):

`print_r($match);` to see what you get:

```
preg_match('/Order ID: ([\d]+)/', $string, $match);
```

Comment: I think you missed out the `i` part. Without knowing about how much space exists between `Order` and `ID`, it's better to give `\s*` or ` *`

Comment: The question shows 1 space and doesn't mention that case case be different.